# Django API architecture

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework, architecture

I have an API and I use DRF with class based views.

My API got these models:

""" Model for System """

```
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

from common_config import custom_model_fields as version_model
from systems.models.manager.manager import SystemManager


class System(models.Model):
    """ Define fields for system model.
    machine(1-1): machine/models/machine.py
    owner(N-N): user/models/user.py
    support(N-N): user/models/user.py
    dealer(1-N): user/models/company.py
    console(1-1): console/models/console.py
    vision(1-N): vision/models/vision.py
    """

    class MarketChoice(models.TextChoices):
        """ Enum for market location """
        AUSTRALIA = 'Australia', _('Australia')
        EUROPE = 'Europe', _('Europe')

    class ProductChoice(models.TextChoices):
        """ Enum for Product """

        SPRAYER = 'Sprayer', _('Sprayer')
        OPTICAL_SORTER = 'Optical sorter', _('Optical sorter')

    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True)
    name = version_model.VersionCharField(
        verbose_name=_('Commercial name of the system'),
        max_length=30,
        default='1',
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        version=1)
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('code'), max_length=30, default='')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Description'), blank=True)
    machine = models.OneToOneField('machine.Machine', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    owner = models.ManyToManyField('users.User', related_name='own')
    support = models.ManyToManyField('users.User', related_name='support')
    dealer = models.ForeignKey('users.Company', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    console = models.OneToOneField('console.Console', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='console')
    market_location = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=MarketChoice.choices, default=MarketChoice.EUROPE)
    is_telemetry_available = models.BooleanField(default=True,
                                                 verbose_name=_('Is the telemetry activated for this system ?'))
    product = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Product type'), max_length=25, choices=ProductChoice.choices,
                               default=ProductChoice.SPRAYER)
    application = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Application'), max_length=30, default='')
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    objects = SystemManager()

    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """ Meta class for System """
        verbose_name = _('System')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Systems')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'System {self.name}'


""" Model for Calculation module """
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Vision(models.Model):
    """ Define fields for vision model.
    Represent a physical calculation module.
    device(1-1): device/models/device.py
    we_version(1-N): version/models/version.py
    setting(1-N): setting/models/setting.py
    camera(N-N): camera/models/camera.py
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True)
    device = models.OneToOneField(
        'device.Device',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    we_version = models.ForeignKey('version.Version', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('Weed Engine Version'))
    we_up_to_date = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Is Weed Engine up to date'))
    we_last_update = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Weed Engine last update date'))
    setting = models.ForeignKey('setting.Setting', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                verbose_name=_('Settings associate to the vision module'), blank=True, null=True)
    system_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('Id of the vision module on the system'))
    camera = models.ManyToManyField('camera.Camera', verbose_name=_('Cameras associated to vision module'))
    installation_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Vision installation date on the system'), null=True,
                                             blank=True)
    system_parent = models.ForeignKey('systems.System', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='vision')

    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """ Meta class for Vision """
        verbose_name = _('Vision')
        verbose_name_plural = _("Visions")


""" Model for Camera """
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Camera(models.Model):
    """ Define fields for camera model.
    Represent a physical camera.
    1-1: device/models/device.py
    1-N: setting/models/setting.py
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True)
    system_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('Id of the vision module on the system'))
    installation_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Camera installation date on the system'), null=True,
                                             blank=True)
    hardware = models.OneToOneField(
        'device.Hardware',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    setting = models.ForeignKey('setting.Setting', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                verbose_name=_('Settings associate to the vision module'), null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """ Meta class for Camera """
        verbose_name = _('Camera')
        verbose_name_plural = _("Cameras")
```

Systems, visions and cameras are 3 differents app.

my API is communicating with an SPA.

For a specific, known system, the SPA needs to get data as:

```
const cameras = [
    {name:"206", module:"206"},
    {name:"204", module:"204"},
    {name:"202", module:"202"},
    {name:"201", module:"201"},
    {name:"203", module:"203"},
    {name:"205", module:"203"},

];
```

The constant had been created for some test reason, the "name" key correspond to the camera's name and "module" to the module's name.

I am wondering if I should create my view on systems, visions or cameras ? Anyway I thought about filtering on the system name/uuid.

Also no matter in which app I put my view, how should I recreate the structure the SPA needs ? should I create a custom serializer and have a specific view using it ? should I return the right structure directly from my database (my favorite option) ? and should I call my view on a url like '/visions-configuration' ? It does not seem very clean and I am not sure it would respect REST convention...

Any help would be great !

Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I've never user Django, but I don't think the answers you're looking for are too Django specific...

> should I return the right structure directly from my database

No.  Are you familiar with the architectural concept of layers?  If not, have a look.  Basically you have code that has different responsibilities - UI vs "business logic" vs data access.  Mixing them is generally bad, for one thing it makes your code  really hard or time consuming to change as the system grows, requirements change, etc.

Regarding your main question: From what I understand you have 3 different models of data you want to work with.  I'm assuming you have a UI (and other system components) which need to deal with these consistently.  A good approach is to come up with a model/data structure that your system (the UI etc) deals with (aka "system model").  I'm not sure if "model" is the right term here - all I mean is some kind of data structure that is not specific to anything external to your system.

That way, yes, you have modify the three input models into your system model, but you only have to do that once, and the rest of your system is only dependent on your system model which you control.  This means the rest of your development is more controlled and stable.

> should I create a custom serializer and have a specific view using it

That sounds ok.  One significant thing to consider with that is do you have your views working directly with the output of the serializer, or off some something that sits in-between.  Note that in both cases the data structure the view is consuming is the same consistent one I called the "system model" above.